# How to add a new section to INI file which already exists?

Tags: c++, windows, ini

I have an INI file which has many sections and keys.
I need to add a new section with a few keys. I used `WritePrivateProfileString` function. This added the new section at the end of the file. Is there a way to add a new section at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using windows API that's not possibile because the order of how sections are written in the .INI is irrilevant. If the file already exist and you add a new section it will be appended at the end of the file.

But there is a tricky solution:

1. Check if it is the very first time that you are writing this new section
2. If yes, then create a new empty .ini and write your section in there
3. Append to your new .ini file the existing one (you dont' have to parse it, you simply need to concatenate two existing text files)
4. Rename or delte the existing .ini file and copy the new one